# ImportError from greenlet with Python 2.7.3 in virtualenv

Tags: python-2.7, compiler-errors, pip, installation, locust

I installed locustio

```
pip install locustio
```

Once installed, I tried running

```
locust --help
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/bin/locust", line 7, in <module>
    from locust.main import main
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/locust/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from core import HttpLocust, Locust, TaskSet, task
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/locust/core.py", line 1, in <module>
    import gevent
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from gevent.hub import get_hub, iwait, wait, PYPY
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 11, in <module>
    from greenlet import greenlet, getcurrent, GreenletExit
ImportError: /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/greenlet.so: undefined symbol: _PyTrash_thread_deposit_object
```

Is the solution to rebuild gevent? If so, how does one go about rebuilding greenlet in debian virtualenv with python 2.7.3? If not, how do I solve this issue without upgrading python?